# enumerated more than once in linq to sql stored procedure call

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm invoking a stored procedure through linq to sql.

```
var qlist = dbc.GetInfoByIDandDate(ID, aDate);  //sp call

if (qlist.Count() == 0)
{
  // error msg
}
else if (qlist.Count() > 1)
{
  // A different Error msg.
}
else
{
    GetInfoByIDandDateResult res = (GetInfoByIDandDateResult) qlist.First();
    string x = res.fieldXname;  // this is a field in the result set.
      ... and so on.
}
```

I've tried various incarnations of this, but always an error.
The error with this iteration is "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Don't enumerate the results multiple times?

Comment: string results = qlist.Count == 0 ? "error 1" : qlist.Count == 1 ? "error 2" : (GetInfoByIDandDateResult) qlist.First().fieldXname;

Comment: Instead of First you could also use Single which would throw an exception if there is not exactly one result. Then you wouldn't need to call Count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling Count() and First(), you are actually enumerating each time.

I'm guessing this would do the trick:

```
var qlist = dbc.GetInfoByIDandDate(ID, aDate).ToList();
```

or, even smarter:

```
var qlist = dbc.GetInfoByIDandDate(ID, aDate).Take(2).ToList();
```

Note that ToList() caches the results so that Count() and First() doesn't run the query again.

Comment: Why is it Take(2) instead of Take(1)?

Comment: I had used the ToList() option previously and was having a different problem with that. Will try again.

Comment: Crap. It worked that time.  I must have had some other issue previously. Tx,el

Comment: Take(2) because otherwise else if (qlist.Count() > 1) would always be false